# How can i delete certain elements when button is pressed in android

Tags: android, button, checkbox, spinner

how would you go about deleting certain elements, such as a spinner and checkbox when you press a button in an app?

Thank you!

Edit:

In my situation, I have a 'duplicate' button when where you click that, a checkbox appears, and you can add as many as you want. so as I want to delete them I'm unsure because I don't have a set variable name for these duplicated checkboxes to delete..below is the code that makes new checkboxes. NOTE: buttontest is the button that should be deleting the other items. I have highlited the code in bold that I think is the problem.

```
  public class create extends AppCompatActivity {


    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    private ArrayList<SearchableSpinner> mSpinners;
    //TODO add the below list of buttons and checkboxes
    private List<AppCompatButton> mButtons = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<CheckBox> mCheckboxes = new ArrayList<>();
    Button buttontest;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




        mSpinners = new ArrayList<>();

        mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout);

        //mLinearLayout.addView(makeSpinner());    // First spinner



        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item added!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                // Handle the click.
                Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner); //Add another spinner


                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)spinner.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.setMargins( 5,  70,  10,  0);

                Resources resources = getResources();
                DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();

                layoutParams.height = (int) (80 * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //80
                layoutParams.width = (int) (240 * ((float)metrics.densityDpi / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)); //240
                spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


                //Add a new button
                AppCompatButton newButton = makeButton();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newButton);      // Add another button
                //TODO add button to the list
                mButtons.add(newButton);


                //Add a new checkbox
                CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);

                //TODO add checkbox to your list
                mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox);
            }
        });

    }


//DUPLICATING ITEMS WHEN + IS PRESSED

    private CheckBox makeCheckbox() {
        //Create new Checkbox
        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);

        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        checkbox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return checkbox;
    }


    private AppCompatButton makeButton() { //creates new buttons i need
        //Create new Button
        AppCompatButton button = new AppCompatButton(this);
        // code for deleting the buttons i need //
        buttontest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontest);
        buttontest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Item removed." , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

                //makeCheckbox().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //buttontest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //TODO when you want to make one of them gone do the following
                //Last button disappears
                if(mButtons.size() > 0) {
                    mButtons.get(mButtons.size()-1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    //mButtons.remove(mButtons.size()-1);
                }

                //Last checkbox disappears
                if(mCheckboxes.size() > 0) {
                    mCheckboxes.get(mCheckboxes.size()-1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  //  mCheckboxes.remove(mCheckboxes.size()-1);
                }


                //Last checkbox disappears
                if(mSpinners.size() > 0) {
                    mSpinners.get(mSpinners.size()-1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                   // mSpinners.remove(mSpinners.size()-1);
                }

                //Please note that the number within get() is the index of the buttons or
                //checkboxes you added so there could
                //be any number of items depends on how many you added

            }
        });



        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));


        return button;
    }

    private Spinner makeSpinner() {
        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        List<String> itemList = csvFile.read();

        //Create new spinner
       // SearchableSpinner spinner = (SearchableSpinner) new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);
        SearchableSpinner spinner = new SearchableSpinner(this);


        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);


        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);



        //Add it to your list of spinners so you can retrieve their data when you click the getSpinner button
        mSpinners.add(spinner);
        return spinner;
    }



    //csv file code
    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {

            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate more or provide code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: Explanation of Answer below**:
OP added added instances of Checkboxes, Buttons, and Spinners in the following  way (Checkbox example):

```
private CheckBox makeCheckbox() {
    //Create new Checkbox
    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);
    // Setup layout
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    checkbox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    return checkbox;
}
```

After the instance of those views were made they were kept in a `List<>` to keep track of like this:

```
private List<CheckBox> mCheckboxes = new ArrayList<>();

    //Add a new checkbox
    CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();

   //TODO add checkbox to your list
   mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox);
```

Finally the new view was added to the root `ViewGroup` which in our case was LinearLayout:

```
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout);
    mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);
```

When making any of the elements disappear and delete their instance, I access their instances through the `List<>` I kept:

```
mCheckboxes.get(mCheckboxes.size()-1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
mCheckboxes.remove(mCheckboxes.size()-1);
```

Here’s what I think you should do: you should create a list of buttons and a list of checkboxes like you did for spinners where you can get instances of the buttons and checkboxes you created:

```
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

private ArrayList<Spinner> mSpinners;
//TODO add the below list of buttons and checkboxes
private List<AppCompatButton> mButtons = new ArrayList<>();
private List<CheckBox> mCheckboxes = new ArrayList<>();
Button buttontest;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




    mSpinners = new ArrayList<>();

    mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout);

    //mLinearLayout.addView(makeSpinner());    // First spinner



    FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
            (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

    floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Handle the click.
            Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
            mLinearLayout.addView(spinner); //Add another spinner


            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)spinner.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.setMargins( 5,  70,  10,  0);
            layoutParams.height = 80;//pixels
            layoutParams.width = 240;//pixels
            spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


            //Add a new button
            AppCompatButton newButton = makeButton();
            mLinearLayout.addView(newButton);      // Add another button
            //TODO add button to the list
            mButtons.add(newButton);


            //Add a new checkbox
            CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
            mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);

            //TODO add checkbox to your list
            mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox);
        }
    });

    //TODO when you want to make one of them gone do the following
    //Last button disappears
    If(mButtons.size() > 0) { 
        mButtons.get(mButtons.size()-1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    //Last checkbox disappears
    If(mCheckboxes.size() > 0) {
       mCheckboxes.get(mCheckboxes.size() - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    //Please note that the number within get() is the index of the buttons or 
   //checkboxes you added so there could 
   //be any number of items depends on how many you added

}


//DUPLICATING ITEMS WHEN + IS PRESSED

private CheckBox makeCheckbox() {
    //Create new Checkbox
    CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);

    // Setup layout
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    checkbox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    return checkbox;
}


**private AppCompatButton makeButton() { //creates new buttons i need
    //Create new Button
    AppCompatButton button = new AppCompatButton(this);
    // code for deleting the buttons i need //
    buttontest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontest);
    buttontest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            buttontest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            makeCheckbox().setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });** 






    // Setup layout
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));


    return button;
}

private Spinner makeSpinner() {
    //opens csv
    InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
    CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
    List<String> itemList = csvFile.read();

    //Create new spinner
    Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);

    // Setup layout
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);


    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Add it to your list of spinners so you can retrieve their data when you click the getSpinner button
    mSpinners.add(spinner);
    return spinner;
}



//csv file code
private class CSVFile {
    InputStream inputStream;

    public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public List<String> read() {

        List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        try {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] row = line.split(",");
                resultList.add(row[1]);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return resultList;
    }
}
}
```

**New edit:**

```
public class create extends AppCompatActivity {


    private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    private ArrayList<Spinner> mSpinners;
    //TODO add the below list of buttons and checkboxes
    private List<AppCompatButton> mButtons = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<CheckBox> mCheckboxes = new ArrayList<>();
    Button buttontest;





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);




        mSpinners = new ArrayList<>();

        mLinearLayout = findViewById(R.id.my_linearLayout);

        //mLinearLayout.addView(makeSpinner());    // First spinner



        FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton =
                (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Handle the click.
                Spinner spinner = makeSpinner();
                mLinearLayout.addView(spinner); //Add another spinner


                LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)spinner.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.setMargins( 5,  70,  10,  0);
                layoutParams.height = 80;//pixels
                layoutParams.width = 240;//pixels
                spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);


                //Add a new button
                AppCompatButton newButton = makeButton();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newButton);      // Add another button
                //TODO add button to the list
                mButtons.add(newButton);


                //Add a new checkbox
                CheckBox newCheckbox = makeCheckbox();
                mLinearLayout.addView(newCheckbox);

                //TODO add checkbox to your list
                mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox);
            }
        });

    }


//DUPLICATING ITEMS WHEN + IS PRESSED

    private CheckBox makeCheckbox() {
        //Create new Checkbox
        CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox(this);

        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        checkbox.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        return checkbox;
    }


    private AppCompatButton makeButton() { //creates new buttons i need
        //Create new Button
        AppCompatButton button = new AppCompatButton(this);
        // code for deleting the buttons i need //
        buttontest = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttontest);
        buttontest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //makeCheckbox().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //buttontest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //TODO when you want to make one of them gone do the following
                //Last button disappears
                if(mButtons.size() > 0) {
                    mButtons.get(mButtons.size()-1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
mButtons.remove(mButtons.size()-1);
               }

               //Last checkbox disappears
              if(mCheckboxes.size() > 0) {
                   mCheckboxes.get(mCheckboxes.size()-1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
mCheckboxes.remove(mCheckboxes.size()-1);
                }
        //Please note that the number within get() is the index of the buttons or
        //checkboxes you added so there could
        //be any number of items depends on how many you added

            }
        });






        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        button.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));


        return button;
    }

    private Spinner makeSpinner() {
        //opens csv
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.shopitems);
        CSVFile csvFile = new CSVFile(inputStream);
        List<String> itemList = csvFile.read();

        //Create new spinner
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(this, Spinner.MODE_DROPDOWN);

        // Setup layout
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        spinner.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        MyListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.listrow, R.id.txtid, itemList);


        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        //Add it to your list of spinners so you can retrieve their data when you click the getSpinner button
        mSpinners.add(spinner);
        return spinner;
    }



    //csv file code
    private class CSVFile {
        InputStream inputStream;

        public CSVFile(InputStream inputStream) {
            this.inputStream = inputStream;
        }

        public List<String> read() {

            List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String[] row = line.split(",");
                    resultList.add(row[1]);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                try {
                    inputStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("Main", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
            return resultList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added TODOs where I made changes

Comment: at  //First checkbox disappears
        if(mCheckboxes) {
            mCheckboxes.get(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } the setVisibility is underlined red?

Comment: also for this part: //TODO add checkbox to your list
                mCheckboxes.add(newCheckbox); it says add(checkbox) in list cannot be applied to android.widget.checkbox

Comment: Alright I made an edit. Please note that the code I added that sets visibility to GONE should be added where you want to make the views disappear so if you have a button that makes views disappear the code should be within the button’s onClick method. Also please note that I changed something that would make the last checkbox and button you added. Let me know what happens.

Comment: thanks! for if(mCheckboxes) {
            mCheckboxes.get(mCheckboxes.size() - 1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } for the mCheckboxes it says  incompatible types: requires boolean

Comment: Yes sorry that was a typo, it was supposed to check the length of the List. I edited it now :). Let me know @crazyCoderN

Comment: :) I appreciate the help. When I click the FAb to add duplicates, then I press the delete button I don't see any thing disappearing (except the delete button)..

Comment: Do you mind showing me your full code file? @crazyCoderN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177829/discussion-between-crazycodern-and-mr-o).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177830/discussion-between-magic-whizz-and-mr-o).

Comment: I sent a message in chat.

Comment: Mr.O, can you start a chat room with me or check the old chat room? thanks :)

Comment: I have a question (not related to this one)

Comment: Hi @Magic_Whizz I just saw your and the link to your question. I’ll check it out

Answer (score 0):

You can't just delete the UI element in Android but you can set the spinner and checkbox visibility to GONE. This completely removes the entities from the screen, but keeps them available in memory for quick future use.

```
spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your requirement you should have control the visibility of the view by the code

```
CheckBox chekbox = (Checkbox)findViewByID(R.id.your_view_id);
```

then on button click you can remove the view by this

```
chekbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

if you set View.GONE then your view is disappear and your view does contain any space behind it. 
if you set View.INVISIBLE then your view is disappear but your view contain his space behind it.